# alter table and insert perf (serial read/write detection)

Tags: sqlite, alter

I have a table 't' with an integer primary key 'k', I'd like to alter the table 't' to add one more column 'c' then fill the 'c' column in a C language iteration loop.

I extracted all the primary keys in a array then plan to prepare() an UPDATE query like this (pseudo code)

```
q=prepare("UPDATE t set c=? where k=?");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)  
{ x=k[i];
  bind(q,0,cvalue); bind(q,1,x);
  step(q);
  ...
}
```

Since the key 'x' that will be presented to the UPDATE query are the primary key in sequence, does SQLITE clever enough to avoid a bsearch on the k=?, in other word, does it detect the 'serial' write access.

Thanx in advance.
Cheers,
Phi

Comment: Why are you asking about implementation details (note: SQLite uses B-trees, not binary searches) when you actually are interested in the performance, which you haven't even measured?

Comment: Because beeing iliterate in DB (learning) I wonder if there are traps when you start to design things.<br> for instance a newbee may not see at first the difference between write(2) and fwrite(3) mmap(2) and malloc(3).<br> I oppsed with bsearch, yes this is btree, still, is there a serial access detection, may be a cache of the last btree search etc, if not it may influence the way you create tables may be avoiding the ALTER on large tables ?

Comment: May be another way to ask. Is it faster do load a table row by row or col by col with successive alter table to add col. And does the fact to load a table row by row or col by col influence data locality in the DB, knowing some indexed col will be heavily solicited having them 'localised', i.e loaded by col if it make sense, may help. May be what I am asking is completly dumb, but when dealing with array in C, FORTRN I like to know what access is better than the other so I may choose my implementations.

Comment: SQLite has a page cache; all top-level pages of the B-tree are likely to be cached. Speed depends on lots of details; the only way to find out is to measure.

Comment: The only way to measure is to code/design :) and I am lazy here, before designing a whole lot of combinations, I'd rather do it once but about right :) based on knowledge of some internals